# Aggregation on multiple fields with a text column

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
StudentName  Height  DateofEntry    PlaceofRecording
Dani           180    1-1-2019       NYC
Dani           181    1-30-2019      Austin
Robbie         150    5-3-2017       LA
Robbie         155    4-3-2019       Atlanta
Robbie         155     4-10-2019     LA

...
```

I want to find, for every student, their maximum height , the most recent date of entry of that maximum height and the PlaceofRecording.
For example:
I want my query to return:

```
Dani   181   1-30-2019  Austin
Robbie 155   4-10-2019  LA
```

So far I've tried this:

```
select StudentName, max(height), max(dateofentry) from table group by 1
```

But I'm not sure how to extract the correct corresponding DateofEntry and the PlaceofRecording. In Robbie's example, since his height value is same in two rows, I then want the row with the most recent DateofEntry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()` to assining numbers to each record, per student sorted by the height descending and the date of entry descending.

```
SELECT studentname,
       height,
       dateofentry,
       placeofrecording
       FROM (SELECT studentname,
                    height,
                    dateofentry,
                    placeofrecording,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY studentname
                                       ORDER BY height DESC,
                                                dateofentry DESC) rn
                    FROM elbat) x
       WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `distinct on` is the best approach:

```
select distinct on (studentname) t.*,
from t
order by t.studentname, t.height desc, t.date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery

```
select q.*
  from table
 where (StudentName, Height, DateofEntry) in
 (
   select StudentName, max(height), max(dateofentry) 
     from table 
    group by StudentName
  ) q
```

Comment: What about PlaceofRecording?